# Zoom an image on scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this code when I scroll the page the image zoom but I want to set the point where the zoom goes. Help me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        const scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.first-block img').css({
            transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+(scroll/50) +'%,0) scale('+(100 + scroll/6)/100+')' 
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: Set the point where the zoom _go_? Also, begging for help won't work very well here.

Comment: @Gabriel Exactly I need to set the point where it is zoomed in, how can I do it? I'm new, where should I ask?

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle please

Comment: @Çağrı https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxdzrf8/2/ If you see with the fact that I cannot decide where the images are zoomed, they are all placed one on top of the other while what I wanted to do was that each image was zoomed in a different point and then exited the screen at a certain point to create an effect of "movement inside".

Comment: Images are not working. Can u control again jsfiddle?

Comment: @Çağrı idk, i can see it but in case I think you can change it, the important thing is the effect